# Ruby: How to add a specific key to every subarray element in the array called and assign it specific value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm not sure if I understood the task correctly, but it's written:
"add a key to every worker in the workers array called "season" and assign it the value "winter""

```
hash1 = { 
  :title => "MegaCorporation",
  :location => "Europe",
  :supervisors => [ 
    {:name=>"Bill", :about=>"blah blah blah 1" },
    {:name=>"John", :about=>"blah blah blah 2"},
    {:name=>"Tiffany", :about=>"blah blah blah 3"}
  ],
  :workers => [ 
    {:name => "Alex", :level => "A"},
    {:name=>"Anna", :level => "B"},
    {:name => "Ashley", :level => "C"},
    {:name => "Mike", :level => "B"}
  ]
}
```

So my code is:

```
hash1[:workers].each { |key,value| key["season"] = "winter"}
```

Did I do what I was asked correctly or what? :)

Comment: btw, not that this is really related to your question, but your variable `array1` is not an array, it's a hash. Kind of a minor nitpick, but it could make your code slightly more understandable/readable.

Comment: I corrected the code, thanks! :)

Comment: Welcome to SO. This question is strange. It could easily be validated with the interpreter. Why haven't you tried in the interpreter instead of asking it here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I would have done it like this:

```
hash1[:workers].each { |worker| worker[:season] = "winter"}
```

Makes sense to read and doesn't defer responsibility to other functions that you might not understand.

Comment: Great, thank you! I think this variant is the best as it indeed shows the logic without any extra methods involved.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, what you did should work. Another way you might have done it could be:

```
hash1[:workers].each { |h| h.merge!(season: 'winter') }
```

Comment: Don't yet have enough reputation to give you, so just thanks! :)